# Return OData compliant JSON using MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, odata

I have a MVC WS that currently returns a JsonResult response with a list of objects (all have the same schema in a given request).

I just got new requirement to make it support OData requests to make it compatible with some services and software.

How can I achieve this easily? I can't use entity framework as the WS returns all kinds of objects (with several schemas, that change at runtime) which I currently abstract as ExpandoObjects that get serialized into Json.

However, I do know the schema before "responding" a request (but this happens at runtime)

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you're good to go

Comment: What do you mean? Just to be clear, I'm asking how to handle OData requests from scratch using Asp.Net MVC, without using Entity Framework, or any other "Odata template" as the schema changes on every request

Comment: OData is a large spec. More than just the data. You'll need metadata generation, function support, etc. etc. You'll essentially be rewriting the OData frameworks out there yourself (with all the dangers and consequences).

Comment: I found what I wanted to, use Open Types and add WebApi OData controller along with my MVC using a Route Prefix to differentiate between "both" apps. I'll post my solution as soon as I can :)